# check CUDA version using "nvidia-smi" and "nvcc -V" gives different result

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I want to installe CUDA 10.1 on Google cloud, however, when I check:

```
root@instance-1:/usr/local# ls
bin  cuda  cuda-10.1  cuda-10.2  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
```

There are 2 folders: cuda-10.1 and cuda-10.2

Here is what cuda-10.1 include:

```
root@instance-1:/usr/local/cuda-10.1# ls
bin  doc  extras  include  lib64  libnsight  libnvvp  LICENSE  nsightee_plugins  nvml  nvvm  README  samples  share  src  targets  tools  version.txt
```

Here is what cuda-10.2 include:

```
root@instance-1:/usr/local/cuda-10.2# ls
doc  LICENSE  README  version.txt
```

It seems that I install 10.1 version, however, when I check CUDA version using `nvidia-smi`:

```
root@instance-1:/usr/local/cuda-10.1# nvidia-smi
Tue Apr 14 04:40:21 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    30W / 250W |     82MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1640      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            82MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It shows 10.2

When I use `nvcc -V`:

```
root@instance-1:/home# nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

It shows 10.1

So, which version did I install? I need to know this so that I can install the right version of cuDNN.

Comment: "I installed CUDA 10.1 on Google cloud". That is the version you installed

Comment: I mean I want to install 10.1, but after I install, these are what I got

Comment: You installed the 10.1 toolkit. nvidia-smi doesn't tell you anything about the CUDA toolkit. Only the maximum CUDA support level of the driver